# React: favorite movies not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm building a mockup Netflix app and part of its functionality is allowing users to add a movie to their favorite movie list, however, when looking at the profile view the favorite movies don't display as expected.

After hours of looking into the problem, I came up empty.

**My Question**: How can I solve this issue so my user's favorite movies can display?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

**Code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import propTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './profile-view.scss';

import { Container, Col, Row, Button, Card, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';

export function ProfileView(props) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [favoriteMovies, setFavoriteMovies] = useState({});
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [birthday, setBirthday] = useState('');

  const [user, setUserData] = useState('');
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const User = localStorage.getItem('user');
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const [favoriteMoviesList, setFavoriteMoviesList] = useState([]);

  const getUserData = () => {
    let user = localStorage.getItem('user');
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    axios
      .get(`https://mymoviesapi2023.herokuapp.com/users/${user}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setUsername(response.data.Username);
        setEmail(response.data.Email);
        setUserData(response.data);
        setFavoriteMoviesList(response.data.FavoriteMovies);
        console.log(response);

        response.data.FavoriteMovies.forEach((movie_id) => {
          let favMovies = props.movies.filter(
            (movie) => movie._id === movie_id
          );
          setMovies(favMovies);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };

  // Delete Profile
  const handleDelete = (e) => {
    const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    axios.delete(`https://mymoviesapi2023.herokuapp.com/users/${user}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    });
    alert(`The account ${user.Username} was successfully deleted.`);
    localStorage.clear();
    window.open('/register', '_self');
  };
  // Update Profile
  const handleUpdate = () => {
    let user = localStorage.getItem('user');
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    axios
      .put(
        `https://mymoviesapi2023.herokuapp.com/users/${user}`,
        {
          Username: username,
          Password: password,
          Email: email,
          Birthday: birthday,
        },
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        }
      )

      .then((response) => {
        alert('Your profile has been updated');
        localStorage.setItem('user', response.data.Username),
          console.log(response.data);
        window.open('/', '_self');
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('Error');
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <h3>Profile</h3>
      </Row>
      <Form>
        <Form.Group className='mb-3' controlId='username'>
          <Form.Label>Username:</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            value={username}
            type='text'
            placeholder='username'
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className='mb-3' controlId='password'>
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            type='password'
            value={password}
            placeholder='Password'
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className='mb-3' controlId='email'>
          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            value={email}
            type='email'
            placeholder='Enter new email'
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className='mb-3' controlId='birthday'>
          <Form.Label>Birthday:</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            onChange={(e) => setBirthday(e.target.value)}
            value={birthday}
            type='date'
            placeholder='birthday'
          />
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
      <Row>
        <Button className='mt-2' onClick={handleUpdate}>
          Update your profile
        </Button>
        <Button className='mt-2 ml-4' onClick={handleDelete}>
          Delete your profile
        </Button>
      </Row>
      <Row className='fav-list'>
        <h4>Favorite Movies:</h4>
      </Row>

      <Row className='mb-3'>
        {favoriteMoviesList.map((movie) => (
          <Col className='mb-3' key={movie._id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Card className='movie-card'>
              <Card.Img
                className='movie-card-img'
                variant='top'
                src={movie.ImageURL}
              />
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title className='movie-card-title'>
                  {movie.Title}
                </Card.Title>
                <Link to={`/movies/${movie._id}`}>
                  <Button className='mt-2' variant='link'>
                    Open
                  </Button>
                </Link>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

ProfileView.propTypes = {
  user: propTypes.shape({
    Username: propTypes.string.isRequired,
    Password: propTypes.string.isRequired,
    Email: propTypes.string.isRequired,
    Birthday: propTypes.string.isRequired,
    FavoriteMovies: propTypes.array.isRequired,
  }),
};
```

Comment: Please format your code in your IDE/code editor and update it in your question with the proper format. so that it's easy to read.

Comment: `setMovies(favMovies);` should be `setFavoriteMovies(favMovies);` and `{favoriteMoviesList.map((movie)` should be `{favoriteMovies.map((movie)`, basically, you're setting data in wrong place and using wrong variable to display the data. Please read your code line by line and understand and verify each line. there could be more errors.